# Checks if argv ends with a .js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do a simple program that listens for an argv from the command line, but im getting this error

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\RLC Tracker & Updater\obfuscate.js:19
    console.log(name.substr(-3));
                     ^
TypeError: name.substr is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\RLC Tracker & Updater\obfuscate
.js:19:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:266:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:596:3)
```

There the code

```
// Select the file as a argv
var name = process.argv.slice(2);

// Checks if the argv is null or empty
if(name == "")
{
    console.log("\nPlease insert the file name.");
}
else if(name.substr(-3) == ".js")
{
    // Code
}
else
{
    //Code
}
```

Comment: Check what type of data type is a variable var name, is it really string on which you can call substr()?

Comment: `slice()` returns an array, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.slice()` returns an array. So:

```
var name = process.argv.slice(2);
```

sets `name` to the array of all arguments starting with index 2. If you just want a specific argument, use an index:

```
var name = process.argv[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.slice()` returns an array. So you want to say something along the lines of:

```
const name = process.argv.slice(2)[0]; // /will be undefined if not provided
if (!name) {
  console.log("\nPlease insert the file name.");
} else if ( /[.][Jj][Ss]/.test(name) ) {
  // name ends with '.js' (or '.JS' or '.Js' or '.jS')
} else {
  // name does not end with '.js'
}
```